# 携帯電話をポケットに入れて歩く「うちに」is using うちに with short "situation" proper?

Tags: grammar

So I was doing a JLPT test, and have found a question like this:

> 携帯電話をポケットに入れて歩く_____、音楽が再生されたり電話をかけてしまったりするのはよくない。
>
> ところに
>
> うちに
>
> なかに
>
> 最中に

The one that seemed to be fitting was うちに, so I have chosen it and it turned to be good answer, however I read that うち should be used with long events, so my question is whether it is proper Japanese or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's proper Japanese and 歩くusually stands for an action that takes a certain duration.